# Oracle proxy connections with springboot

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot, entitymanager

we are using oracle-proxy configuration to build the dateSource. in XML :

```
<orcl:pooling-datasource id="dataSource" url="${oracle.url}"
    username="${oracle.username}" password="${oracle.password}">
    <orcl:connection-properties>validationQuery=select 1 from dual</orcl:connection-properties>
    <orcl:connection-cache-properties>ValidateConnection=true</orcl:connection-cache-properties>
    <orcl:username-connection-proxy
        connection-context-provider="usernameProvider" />
</orcl:pooling-datasource>

<!-- Configure bean UserProvider -->
<bean id="usernameProvider" class="com.provider.UserProvider" />
```

`UserProvider` : class implements `ConnectionUsernameProvider` to get the connected user name . That it works !

Now we switch to `Spring-boot`. how can we transform the XML configuration to java class configuration using `ProxyDataSource` / `OracleDataSource` ?

Comment: to solve the problem:
- I imported my xml file:
    @ImportResource ("classpath *: META-INF / spring / persistence-applicationContext.xml")

- in the application.properties file: comment all the properties
    # spring.datasource.xxx
to ensure that Spring Boot did not enable the default DataSource